# Can I set the base path outside of my application directory when binding an image source path to a relative path in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, path, relative-path

So I'm trying to display an image that is ouside the path of my application.  I only have a relative image path such as "images/background.png" but my images are somewhere else, I might want to choose that base location at runtime so that the binding maps to the proper folder.  Such as "e:\data\images\background.png" or "e:\data\theme\images\background.png"

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePathWithRelativePath}"/>
```

Is there any way to specify either in XAML or code behind a base directory for those images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a static field say BasePath in code behind

```
class Utility
{
    public static BasePath;
}
```

assign it the path that you want to use as base path

declare a converter like this:

```
public class RelativePathToAbsolutePathConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //conbine the value with base path and return
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // return whatever you want
    }
}
```

Update your binding to use a converter

```
<Window.Resources>
<local:RelativePathToAbsolutePathConverter x:Key="RelativePathToAbsolutePathConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Image Source="{Binding Path=ImagePathWithRelativePath, Converter={StaticResource RelativePathToAbsolutePathConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the right direction.

Turns out I need to combine the path and the relative path in the Convert method, not the ConvertBack method.  I'm still marking this right as it solved my problem.

I thought I might need a converter, and was just thinking there might be a different solution... either way... Thanks!

Comment: it was coz i didn't tested my code, anyways, thanks for pointing my mistake, I have updated my answer